# ArrayLists and Polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism

I'm trying to implement a monopoly-style game in java as part of a school project but I've run into an issue that I cant resolve or seem to find an answer to the question that I have.  The problem is that I'm getting a classCastException in my code, I think I've figured out why I'm getting it (i was originally trying to cast type `Property` onto the `newPosition` variable below)but now I need to find a way to implement the code so that I can avoid it.

The issue is i have a superclass `Square` which has 3 possible subclasses `Property`, `Go` and `FreeParking`.  I'm storing my board as an ArrayList but I need to access the methods pertaining to `Property` objects to calculate rent etc.  How can I access these methods if when I access the property from the ArrayList it it of type `Square`.

Apologies in advance if this doesn't make too much sense.

```
public abstract class Square {
    private String name;
    private boolean isAvailable;
    private Player owner;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Property extends Square{
    private String colour;
    private int buyHouset;
    private int rent1House;
    private int rent2House;
    private int rent3House;
    private int rentHotel;
    private int numHouses;
    private int rent;
    private int price;

    //getters and setters
}

public static void takeTurn(Player player, Dice die, ArrayList<Square> board) {
    System.out.println(player.getGamertag() + "'s turn");

    //get value from roll of die
    int move =  askToRoll();

    String gamertag = player.getGamertag();

    //if player does not quit continue with turn
    if(move > 0) {
        //get player current position and add roll of die
        int newSpaceIndex = player.getPosition() + move;

        //if players new position exceeds the array of squares, return to 0 index and add remainder 
        //add credits for passing Go
        //else update position
        if (newSpaceIndex > 11) {
            player.setPosition(newSpaceIndex - 12);
            Go.passGoAction(player);
        }else {
            player.setPosition(newSpaceIndex);
        }


        if(player.getPosition() == 1) {
            Square newPosition = board.get(player.getPosition());
            System.out.println(gamertag + " new position " + newPosition.getName());
        }else if(player.getPosition() == 6) {
            FreeParking.freeParkingAction();
        } else {
            Square newPosition = board.get(player.getPosition());
            System.out.println("____________________");
            System.out.println("Land on " + newPosition.getName());

            if(newPosition.getOwner() != null) {
                Player owner = newPosition.getOwner();

/* *****THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS STEMING FROM*****
*THE  newPosition.getRent() method can not be accessed as newPosition 
*is defines as Square
*/
                System.out.println(owner.getGamertag() + " demands you pay " + newPosition.getRent() + " credits!");





            }else {
                System.out.println("What would you like to do now? ...\n"
                        + "1. Buy property\n"
                        + "2. End turn");
                int input = in.nextInt();
                boolean valid = false;
                do {
                    switch(input) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("You now own controlling stock of " + newPosition.getName());
                        player.setOwnsProperty(newPosition);
                        newPosition.setOwner(player);
                        valid = true;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Ending turn");
                        valid=true;
                        break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Invalid input, please select one of the options 1-2");
                            valid = false;
                            break;
                    }
                }while(!valid);
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("END TURN: " + player);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that a particular Square **is a** Property, cast it and assign it to the appropriate type.

```
Property newPosition = (Property)board.get(player.getPosition());
```

Edit: In future, you might also want to consider putting the logic that goes with a particular type of Square into a subclass.  In other words, something like `square.process(player)`, where Property, Go, and FreeParking each implements the `process(player)` method with appropriate logic.  That goes into more detailed concepts around object-oriented design, and may not be relevant to you right now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  I had tried casting that specific square like you described but that was causing the classCastException.  I thought it was because I was trying to downcast a Square to a Property?

Comment: What is the exact exception message and stack trace?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: monopoly.Go cannot be cast to Monopoly.Property ... ah. that is obviously the issue then

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this snippet helps you to understand the concept

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Square newPosition = new Property();
        if (newPosition instanceof Property) {
            System.out.println("newPosition cast as Property");
            Property newPositionAsProperty = ((Property) newPosition);
            int newRent = newPositionAsProperty.getRent();
            // or
            newRent = ((Property) newPosition).getRent();
        }
        // To understand better
        if (newPosition instanceof Square) {
            System.out.println("newPosition instanceof Square");
            ((Square)newPosition).getName();
        }
        if (Square.class.isAssignableFrom(Property.class)) {
            System.out.println("Square.class.isAssignableFrom(Property.class)");
            ((Square)newPosition).getName();
        }
        if (Property.class.isInstance(newPosition)) {
            System.out.println("Property.class.isInstance(newPosition)");
            ((Property)newPosition).getName();
        }
        if (Square.class.isInstance(newPosition)) {
            System.out.println("Square.class.isInstance(newPosition)");
            ((Square)newPosition).getName();
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
newPosition cast as Property
newPosition instanceof Square
Square.class.isAssignableFrom(Property.class)
Property.class.isInstance(newPosition)
Square.class.isInstance(newPosition)
```